# Angular filter more then 1 item in table

Tags: angular

I have the following function which filters out the 'title' in my bootstrap table. I would like to also filter by 'id'.

```
  search(term: string) {
    if (!term) {
      this.filterData = this.data;
    } else {
      this.filterData = this.data.filter(x =>
         x.title.trim().toLowerCase().includes(term.trim().toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  }
```

How can I add the 'id' parameter as well?

The json array that is being filtered looks like this

```
[
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use && operator with the filter,

```
 this.filterData = this.data.filter(x =>
         x.title.trim().toLowerCase().includes(term.trim().toLowerCase()) &&
         x.id == yourId)
  );
```

Comment: Just a quick update, I changed && to || so the user can search by either value. Also I have done the following in the filter x.id === Number(term)